# How can I remove blank Column when exporting in csv use phpexcel

Tags: csv, codeigniter, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I export to csv from php using phpexcel library. In my file i want to export multidimensional array. My first, and  second row set as header, that have different count column:

| Name | Address | Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item | Qty |  |
| Grace | Texas | 098987 |
| Orange | 2 |  |

When I exported on csv it becomes

```
"Name","Address","Phone Number"
"Item,"Qty",""
"Grace","Texas","098987"
"Orange","2",""
```

[image]

How can I remove double quote on empty column?

Comment: Why would you want to? Don't you want your arrays to be an even length?

Comment: could you show one or two lines of your excel, for me it looks like you would want your header to look like `Name | Address | Phone Number | Item | Qty` and your data row like `Grace | Texas | 098987 | Orange | 2` ?

Comment: @Vickel I've updated with excel